# ngnix not serving assets of my rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, assets

I'm running a rails app in prodction with nginx an apache2.

The application starts properly, but the assets were not served by nginx. The Assets are under public/assets available.

But nginx says 404 Not Found.

any ideas how to solve this issue?

its a debian server with plesk17

Apache config looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Apache or Nginx???

Comment: Nginx said 404 Not Found

Comment: but the app is running with phusion passanger for apache, nginx is need for https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

restarting server and resassign ssl certificate solves my problem